# Google Spreadsheet "Publish for web" only displaying "Loading..."

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet with columns all over the place and I only need a selected few of them so what I did was create a new spreadsheet and used the **importrange** function to format my spreadsheet properly and with only the content I wanted from the original spreadsheet.  Everything looked great and I tried to use the "Publish to the web..." feature, but when you follow [**the link**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ij_gDzGjZsdbvGaf4I9-AAKAKa1_Mui1Jsa0zpeKJM4/pubhtml), the columns are stuck "Loading..."

I went to the original spreadsheet and made that start publishing to the web also to see if that if it just some permission issue that that might solve, but no dice.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I clicked your link there it works now. I had the same problem and it seems that it's just an internal server loading error. I only had to wait about 30 minutes and then mine started to work properly.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input.  I'm glad it eventually decided to kick in.